# Javascript variable scope question

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, scope

I'm having trouble resolving a scope issue with my javascript.
I have an array, dog[] that is defined from JSON, that I need access to from inside a nested function.

```
function blah(json) {
 for (var u = 0; u < json[0][1][u].length; u ++ ) {
    var dog = 'k' + json[0][1][u].doggies;
    console.log(dog); // prints array of doggie strings
    $('#puppy').click(function(dog) {    // dog is passed in the function
       console.log(dog); // Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #[object Object]
       $('#' + dog).css('display, 'none');
     });
   }
 }
```

when I dont pass dog into the click function: i get:

```
 $('#puppy').click(function() {
  console.log(dog) // (12)  main.js:122k4c812e3a7275e10331000000 - this is the last value in the array - from safari console
  $('#' dog).css('display', 'none);
   }
```

Does anyone have any suggestions to get the array with every element passed into the click function?
Or am i calling the css method incorrectly to hide those divs?

Comment: Pardon me, but doesn't `json[0][1][u].length` change with each iteration of `u`? This seems very flaky to me.

Comment: @Peter Ajtai, I already mentioned that in my answer.  @Robusto, Good catch; no clue what's going on there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Problem 1

Closures bind the entire function's scope, and not individual variables or values.

Take this code for example:

```
function foo() {
    var i, func;

    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        if (i == 0) {
            func = function () {
                alert(i);
            }
        }
    }

    func();
}

foo();
```

You may expect `foo` to cause `0` to be alerted.  However, the value of `i` has changed since the function assigned to `func` was created; the call to `func` alerts "10".

Here is another example illustrating the concept:

```
function foo() {
    var i = 42;

    function func() {
        alert(i);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        // do nothing
    }

    func();
}

foo();
```

Try to figure out what will be alerted, and run the code as a test.

### Problem 2

The second problem is that variables are bound at the function scope (and not the block scope as you expect).

Take this code:

```
function foo() {
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        var j = i;
    }

    alert(j);
}

foo();
```

You may expect this code to alert "undefined", throw a run-time error, or even throw a syntax error.  However, "10" is alerted.  Why?  In JavaScript, the above code is translated into effectively:

```
function foo() {
    var i;

    var j;

    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        j = i;
    }

    alert(j);
}

foo();
```

It should be more clear from this example that "10" is indeed alerted.

### Solution

So how do you fix your problem?  The simplest way is to change your logic: instead of attaching one event handler per dog, attack one event handler per collection of dogs.  For example:

```
function blah(json) {
    $('#puppy').click(function () {
        var u, dog;

        for (u = 0; u < json[0][1][u].length; u++) {
            dog = 'k' + json[0][1][u].doggies;

            console.log(dog);

            $('#' + dog).css('display', 'none');
        }
    });
}
```

If you're interested in the "proper" transformation of your existing code (i.e. having the same behaviours, except with the bug fixed), I can give you an example of that as well.  However, the solution I gave above is a much better solution and results in cleaner code.

Comment: The first argument of a call back in `.click()` is the `event` that happened, so you should remove `dog` from `function(dog) {` in your solution.... just so as not to confuse the issue.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! Very helpful explanation. I will study your example  in more depth when I'm less sleep deprived.

Comment: @Peter Ajtai, Thanks for catching that.  I copy-pasted the original code and basically just swapped two lines.  I'll fix it.

Answer (score 2):

### Important Note:

You forgot to close your quote. This:

```
$('#' + dog).css('display, 'none');
```

Should be:

```
$('#' + dog).css('display', 'none');
```

---

### An Improved Loop:

There are several problems with your script. I'll concentrate on the overall logical structure of the loop.

Instead of attaching many handlers to `.click()`, just attach one handler that iterates over you JSON using jQuery's **[`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)**. The first argument of the callback of `.each()` is the index number and the second argument is the value. You can make use of those 2 by naming the arguments or by using `arguments[0]` and `arguments[1]`. I show the former method below:

I've added some more test output for demonstration purposes:

```
function blah(json) {
     $('#puppy').click(function() { 

          // iterate over each json[0][1]
        $.each(json[0][1], function(index, value) {

              // Your original 2 lines
            console.log(value);
            $('#' + value).css('display', 'none');

              // This is just test output, so you can see what is going
              // on.
            $("body").append("Number " + index + " is " + value ".<br/>");
        });
     });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just give the doggies a class `.dog` and hide them when `#puppy` is clicked?

```
$("#puppy").click(function() {
    $(".dog").hide();
});
```

Or since your dog's IDs seem to start with k, you *might* consider something like this:

```
$("#puppy").click(function() {

    // hide everything with ID beginning with 'k'
    $('[id^=k]').hide();
});
```

Comment: Such a simple solution compared to everyone else. +1 for using a CSS class as selector.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass the dog value into the jquery click event as you have done there. The click function signature is:

```
$(object).click(function(){


});
```

You can't pass dog in like this. Even if the function expected a parameter, naming it dog would cause issues. You may need to store the values of dog in a more global scope so that when the click event occurs, you still have access to it.

Comment: Shadowing.... but in this case `dog` as an argument actually represents the `event`, since it's the first argument of a call back in `.click()`.

Comment: @KP, I'm sorry; I misread your answer.  (I missed two words and that totally threw off the meaning...  My bad!)